# If $f : R \rightarrow R \cup \{- ∞, ∞\}$ is continuous then f is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For x such that $f(x) = ∞ $ how to establish continuity in order to show that these function is measurable.

How are the open sets for these topology?

Comment: generated by open sets $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \Bbb R$; rays of the form $[-\infty,a)$ with $a \in \Bbb R$; rays of the form $(a,\infty]$ with $a \in \Bbb R$

Comment: See here for some insight: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817063/topology-and-borel-sets-of-extended-real-line